# Two array combine or flipped

Tags: php, arrays

I have this two arrays:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => 518
  1 => 519
  2 => 520
  3 => 521
]
```

and this one:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
  3 => "3"
]
```

Can someone please help me how to achieve like this..

```
array:4 [▼
 518=>1
  519=> 2
 520 => 3
  521 => 3
]
```

I do not know if it is possible or not like

Comment: What have you tried so far? foreach would be a good start.

Comment: SO is not here to write the code for you without even providing the minimum effort from your side.

Answer (score 3):

You can use built in function `array_combine` to achieve this:

```
$arr1 =array(
  0 => 518,
  1 => 519,
  2 => 520,
  3 => 521,
);

$arr2 =array(
  0 => "1",
  1 => "2",
  2 => "3",
  3 => "3",
);
$new_array = array_combine($arr1,$arr2);
print_r($new_array);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/SQOEF)

Comment: If integers are required: `array_map('intval', array_combine($arr1,$arr2))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through and use the key to associate between your arrays.  You have a little type juggling to do.

```
<?php
$one = 
[
  0 => 518,
  1 => 519,
  2 => 520,
  3 => 521
];

$two = 
[
  0 => "1",
  1 => "2",
  2 => "3",
  3 => "3"
];

$desired =
[
  518 => 1,
  519 => 2,
  520 => 3,
  521 => 3
];

foreach($one as $k=>$v)
{
    $out[$v] = (int) $two[$k];
}    

if($desired === $out) {
    echo 'All good.';
}
```

Output:

```
All good.
```